Unexpected re-renders with useMemo and dynamic object keys in dependencies array
I'm encountering an issue with React's useMemo hook when using dynamic object keys in the dependencies array. I have a complex component that needs to memoize a value based on a subset of an object's properties, but the keys of this object can change dynamically.
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react';

const ExpensiveComponent = ({ data, keysToWatch }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => {
    console.log('Recalculating memoized value');
    return Object.entries(data)
      .filter(([key]) => keysToWatch.includes(key))
      .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => acc + value, 0);
  }, [data, keysToWatch, ...Object.keys(data).filter(key => keysToWatch.includes(key))]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Memoized Value: {memoizedValue}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment Count: {count}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
  const [keysToWatch, setKeysToWatch] = useState(['a', 'b']);

  return (
    <div>
      <ExpensiveComponent data={data} keysToWatch={keysToWatch} />
      <button onClick={() => setData({ ...data, d: 4 })}>Add 'd' to data</button>
      <button onClick={() => setKeysToWatch([...keysToWatch, 'c'])}>Add 'c' to keysToWatch</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

The issue is that the memoized value is recalculating more often than expected. Specifically:
When I click "Increment Count", the memoized value recalculates, even though neither data nor keysToWatch have changed.
When I click "Add 'd' to data", the memoized value recalculates, even though 'd' is not in keysToWatch.
I expected the memoized value to only recalculate when:
a) The values of the watched keys in data change
b) The keysToWatch array changes
How can I modify this code to achieve the expected behavior? I've tried various approaches with useCallback and custom hooks, but I can't seem to get it right. Is there a way to create a stable reference for the dependencies that only changes when the relevant subset of data or keysToWatch changes?

tldr: remove ...Object.entries() from dependency array of useMemo 
You have already specified data as a dependency for the memo. Including dynamic dependency (...spread of data) creates dynamic dependency array, which causes an error:
Error: Warning: The final argument passed to useMemo changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant.

Previous: [[object Object], a,b, a, b]
Incoming: [[object Object], a,b,c, a, b, c]

Set dependencies array of useMemo to [data, keysToWatch] 
Regarding to the problem that including the 'd' key causes re-calculation - again, you specified data as dependency for useMemo, so it will re-calculate
If you want to skip re-calculation after adding 'd' then you should remove data dependency, but I would assume that this will break your desired functionality.
edit1. if dependency array is only keysToWatch, then memo value won't change if you include/change key of data, even if it is already present in keysToWatch
